# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin.The binary version of its metadata is1.7.1, expected version is1.5.1 tetera para hacer mate

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am making a register and login application when I try to run it but this error appears : Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.

and I can't find which file I have to downgrade

this is the build:gradle(app):

```
android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.loginandregister"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}
```

dependencias :

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
}
```

this is the build:gradle(LoginAndRegister) :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.1'
    }
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

It would help me a lot if someone points me to the error

sorry if it's misspelled i don't write well in english

I would not know what to say try to look for the :

```
ext.kotlin_version = ''
```

to change version or dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1' // downloads 1.7.1 Metadata
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

all this was taken from another answer